# Importing an SQLite file into Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I've been trying (unsuccessfully) to import an existing SQLite database into Python. I want to write a script in Python to run a large set of database queries all at once.

When I try to connect to the SQLite file, Python writes a new file with the same name in folder I'm trying to connect to. Code as follows:

```
import sqlite3;

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\Test\Databasename.sqlite")

c = conn.cursor()
```

When I then try to run queries on specific tables, Python displays 'cannot find table (or similar)' because it has created a new database file; as opposed to importing the existing one.

How do I get Python to open my existing file? I've had a lengthy scour on here, I haven't been able to find an answer sadly :()

Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

You're using backslashes in your path. Python will use them to escape the following character. E.g. `\t` will become a `TAB` (hex 09) character.

Either escape your backslashes or use a `raw` string.

```
sqlite3.connect("C:\\Test\\Databasename.sqlite")
- or -
sqlite3.connect(r"C:\Test\Databasename.sqlite")
```

Comment: I've given this a go - it's still giving me the 'no such table' error!

The subsequent code I've used is sql = "SELECT * FROM table1" followed by cursor.execute(sql). Any further ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the content of your sqlite DB, so I can't verify if the table exists or not.